# Can medically required blood donations (phlebotomy) be tax deductible?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction

Can medically required blood donations (phlebotomy) be tax deductible when the blood center sends it to area hospitals? This isn't a typical blood donation that I know is not tax deductible. I have to have a pint removed weekly, they then re-use the blood.

Comment: Its not clear if you mean as a medical expense, a charitable deduction, or an other proposed way?

Comment: What do you mean by "medically required"?

Comment: Ordered by a doctor.  For instance if I take oxy, I'm a hobbyist and a criminal, and illegal losses can't be deducted beyond illegal gains, and hobbies are never deductible.  If I take oxy because a doctor prescribed it, then it's a legitimate medical expense that is treated as such in tax law.

Comment: Are you paying for the removal of your blood, and asking if that expense is deductible?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Judging by the OP's username (Up North, Wisconsin), I'm going to guess "US" unless he comes back and tells us a different country.

Answer (score 5):

You would need to talk to a tax expert to be certain, but in general medical expenses can be deducted to the extent that they are more than 10% of your adjusted gross income. So if your gross income is $100,000 and your total qualified medical expenses are $12,000, you can deduct $2,000. Plus you need enough *other* deductions (state/local taxes, mortgage interest, etc.) that it makes more sense to itemize than to take the standard deduction.

Finally, make sure you keep *detailed* records to prove your claimed expenses in case of an audit. Medical expenses are a red flag for audits due to their relatively high rate of fraud and difficulty to prove.